# .NET equivalent or alternative to Java's GlyphVector?

Tags: java, .net, graphics, text, ikvm

I'm in the process of porting a Java program to .NET using [IKVM](http://ikvm.sourceforge.net). Unfortunately IKVM's Graphics2D implementation throws a NotImplementedException in [drawGlyphVector](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html), i.e. it needs to be "fleshed out" with a .NET implementation (or by reducing it to calls of other IKVM Graphics2D methods which *are* implemented).

Any ideas for an equivalent in .NET which I could use to provide an implementation for that method in IKVM?

---

**Edit #1**: My first hunch was to simply call `GlyphVector.getOutline()` and then fill that shape. Unfortunately, `getOutline()` threw its own `NotImplementedException`.

Well it seems that now I'm looking for an alternative to `GlyphVector` itself: NetGlyphVector, the IKVM version of `Glyphvector` is basically just a stub class with nearly all methods currently throwing NotImplementedExceptions...

So ***does anyone know a .NET equivalent to Java's `GlyphVector` class?***

Comment: Hi Epaga,
Does this help you? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844913/is-there-a-equivalent-in-c-sharp-for-the-java-method-getglyphoutline

Comment: This might be useful too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522958/font-rendering-with-glyph-information

Comment: It is possible this helps: 
[Stackoverflow - getGlyphOutline equivalent in C#][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844913/is-there-a-equivalent-in-c-sharp-for-the-java-method-getglyphoutline

Answer (score 2):

There is not an equivalent in .NET yet. From Microsoft's website:

> In the Java language, this class represents a collection of glyphs and
>   contains geometric information for the placement of each glyph in
>   transformed coordinate space.
>
> In the .NET Framework, there is no direct equivalent.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/b6s81f68%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

You should probably just create your own class and implement the methods you need using the Java source, otherwise you will have to find another way to convert your code.

Comment: If you implement them, please submit the changes back to the IKVM project.