# Is there a equivalent in C# for the Java method getGlyphOutline?

Tags: c#, java, .net

I am converting some Java code to C#. This code is using getGlyphOutline from GlyphVector. Any idea if there an equivalent in C# or .NET?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to use P/Invoke, see [GetGlyphOutline (gdi32)](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32/GetGlyphOutline.html?diff=y)